# Can't start working with docker

Tags: docker

I use ubuntu 16.04.

Suddenly (sorry), I can't run docker. 
When I run command in the terminal I only have this (expected output was info about client and daemon versions):

```
$ sudo docker --version 
Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec
```

When I run commands line this

```
$ sudo docker ps
```

I have nothing for long time:

[image]

How can I overcome this problem?

```
$ sudo service docker status
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Ср 2017-01-04 18:14:48 MSK; 12s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 9534 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 9534 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

янв 04 18:14:47 kenenbek dockerd[9534]: time="2017-01-04T18:14:47.446210980+03:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit."
янв 04 18:14:47 kenenbek dockerd[9534]: time="2017-01-04T18:14:47.447160673+03:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
янв 04 18:14:47 kenenbek dockerd[9534]: .................time="2017-01-04T18:14:47.469385119+03:00" level=info msg="Firewalld running: false"
янв 04 18:14:47 kenenbek dockerd[9534]: time="2017-01-04T18:14:47.881263583+03:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP addr
янв 04 18:14:48 kenenbek dockerd[9534]: time="2017-01-04T18:14:48.736641043+03:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
янв 04 18:14:48 kenenbek dockerd[9534]: time="2017-01-04T18:14:48.790061315+03:00" level=fatal msg="Error creating cluster component: error while loadi
янв 04 18:14:48 kenenbek systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
янв 04 18:14:48 kenenbek systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
янв 04 18:14:48 kenenbek systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
янв 04 18:14:48 kenenbek systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

When I get such output when I run:

```
$ sudo service docker restart 
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: Is the docker daemon running? $sudo service docker also how did you install Docker? have you tried:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/
or
https://get.docker.com/
these have always worked for me

Comment: @YFP, yes, I installed it from first link. I worked fine, but today I have problems. I've updated question with "sudo service docker status"

Comment: So the daemon does not look like it is running which means the docker binary will not be able to connect (thus the hang you see). The status clearly shows that something has borked here - What do you get is you HUP/restart the service?

Comment: @YFP I've updated

Comment: Awesome! have you tried Mark's answer from below? the error messages you are getting look similar to the bug he referenced :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a docker swarm certificate related issue as reported [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/24132)

A solution to this problem will be released in version `1.13`. For now you can try forcing recreating the swarm as explained [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/24132#issuecomment-251736548).